Can't use many params in tags: annotation value not of an allowable type
Given:
Java 8
In build.gradle:
dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.20.1'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.20.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.2.0'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.codeborne:selenide:6.19.0' 
}

Here my feature file:
Feature: Feature to test Google search functionality

  @RegenerationTest
  Scenario: Search in Google search with hardcode text
    Given User is on Google search page
    When User enters a text in search box
    And Hit Enter
    Then User is navigated to search results

  @ignore
  Scenario: Search in Google search with pass one param
    Given User is on Google search page
    When User enters a text in search box with param "cucumber how pass parameters"
    And Hit Enter
    Then User is navigated to search results

  @SmokeTest
  Scenario Outline: Search in Google search with many pass params
    Given User is on Google search page
    When User enters a text in search box with param "<TextParam>"
    And Hit Enter
    Then User is navigated to search results

    Examples:
      |  TextParam|
      |  Java last release      |
      |  Design patterns        |

And here my runner
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="classpath:features/google_search.feature", tags = "not @ignore")
public class GoogleSearchRunner {
}

This runner run all scenarios exclude scenario annotated by @ignore. OK.
Now I want to start only scenarios annottated by @RegenerationTest and @SmokeTest.
I try this:
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="classpath:features/google_search.feature", tags = {"@RegenerationTest, @SmokeTest"})
public class GoogleSearchRunner {
}

or this:
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="classpath:features/google_search.feature", tags = {"@RegenerationTest", "@SmokeTest"})
public class GoogleSearchRunner {
}

But get error:
> Task :app:compileTestJava FAILED
/cucumberfxtestproject/step/GoogleSearchRunner.java:8: error: annotation value not of an allowable type
@CucumberOptions(features="classpath:features/google_search.feature", tags = {"@RegenerationTest", "@SmokeTest"})
                                                                         ^

1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
